# how to route 2 instances of mpd in 2 separate pairs(stereo) of output (playback) ports in pulse audio

Tags: routing, pulseaudio, streaming, jack, mpd

I want basically to output one instance of mpd (a stereo signal) to line out (front) , and another instance of mpd to line out (rear). It appears that no pulse audio tutorial deals with this case (when searching for "multiple" streams, the results deal with mixing streams to the "default" output soundcard", or with playing the same stream from line out and HDMI or something similar).

Specifically, I am using `pulseaudio-jack-sink` -as I use JACK as my main sound server- which I have configured to have 4 channels

```
pactl load-module module-jack-sink channels=4 connect=false
```

and from `mpd.conf` and `mpd2.conf` I have

```
# An example of a pulseaudio output (streaming to a remote pulseaudio server)
#
audio_output {
        type            "pulse"
        name            "My Pulse Output"
#       server          "remote_server"         # optional
#       sink            "remote_server_sink"    # optional
}
```

This uses the default pulseaudio output though and this is specifically what I want to avoid. So how can I do it ?

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Music Player Demon (MPD), but as it as a normal audio application, I would expect the two server instances to show up as two applications, and then you can use the normal Pulseaudio controls to redirect them.

So make sure the `name` entry in `mpd.conf` and `mpd2.conf` is different (e.g. `MPD 1` and `MPD 2`), start both MPD server, run `pavucontrol` and see as what they show up, and if you can select their output sink in the normal way.

Pulseaudio remembers the output sink by the application name, so that is all that should be needed. On next start of the MPD servers, they'll get assigned the same sink for each again.